# How to do a triple integral with singularity in python?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have an integral

```
tplquad(lambda pz,py,px:f(px,py,pz),0, pi, lambda px: 0, lambda px: pi,lambda px, py: 0, lambda px, py: pi )
```

The integrand f(px,py,pz) has singularity at surface

```
cos(px)+cos(py)+cos(pz)=C
```

Because of that, sicipy gives warning for it. 
How to handle this? How to exclude surface in tplquad or do a principal value integral in python?